# Blurring a div blurs other divs

Tags: css

When I blur a div, other divs near to it also get blurred and semi-transparent at the edge near the blurred div.

Here's a demonstration: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezpdy

How can I prevent other divs from getting blurred?

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to place the `.background-image` behind all other elements.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/driDz

```
.background-image {
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Or put the `#test` above the `.background-image`

```
#test {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Both ways work fine.

Answer (score 1):

`#test` isn't getting blurred. Because `.background-image` is blurred by `5px`, it affects `5px` around it.